# Selenium webDriverWait ожидание вновь созданного frame

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

Создается новый frame, не обходимо переключится в него делаю так `wait.Until(ch => ch.SwitchTo().Frame(1));`
Выбрасывается ошибка фрейм не найден, если выставить паузу `Thread.Sleep(3000);` тогда фрейм находится и в него можно зайти. Но фрейм может грузится 5 сек и даже 40. Пробовал так `wait.IgnoreExceptionTypes(typeof(NoSuchElementException));` ошибка остается. Есть способ не делая цикл обхода проверки доступности фрейма зайти в него?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть замечательный класс `ExpectedConditions`, а в нем метод `FrameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By)`, который как раз ждет появления фрейма и переключает контекст в него:

```
wait.Until(ec.FrameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.CssLocator('div.frame')))
```

Comment: Такой класс не доступен, может что подключить надо для него?

Comment: @ДмитрийВалерьевич, конечно. https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_ExpectedConditions.htm

Comment: Обратите внимание текущая версия помечена, что будет удалена. У меня проблемма решилась обновлением из nuget.